# How to validate words count in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to see how can I validate words count in laravel , for example if a text area accepts only 250 words?

Could some one help me I am using laravel 4.1

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Laravel has a speciic method for this, but you can do it with some simple php.

**In your controller:**

```
public function store(){

    $text = Input::get('textarea');

    if(count(explode(' ', $text)) > 250)
        return 'more than 250 words';

}
```

Comment: thanks for your help I guess I have to have a custom one

Comment: You can just use str_word_count().

Comment: `str_word_count()` won't work for other languages than English

Answer (score 7):

For Laravel 5.1 and using the advice of Lisa and Richard Le Poidevin, I did the nexts steps based on [Laravel 5.1: Validation Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules) and all works fine and clean:

Created a new ValidatorServiceProvider extending Service Provider in "app/Providers/" for all the validation rules including the Validator::extend method that does the validation and the Validator::replacer that returns a formmated message so we can tell the user the word limit.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ValidatorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(){
        Validator::extend('maxwords', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            $words = preg_split( '@\s+@i', trim( $value ) );
            if ( count( $words ) <= $parameters[ 0 ] ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        Validator::replacer('maxwords', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
            return str_replace(':maxwords', $parameters[0], $message);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register(){
        //
    }
}
```

Then, register the Service Provider in config/app.php:

```
App\Providers\ValidatorServiceProvider::class,
```

For the validation language response is resources/lang/en/validation.php:

```
"maxwords" => "This field must have less than :maxwords words.",
```

Answer (score 3):

What I ended up doing when I ran into this problem last year was this:

```
Validator::extend( 'word_count', function ( $field, $value, $parameters ) {
    $words = preg_split( '@\s+@i', $value );
    if ( count( $words ) <= $parameters[ 0 ] ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
} );
```

This takes any non-whitespace set of characters and considers it a 'word', then counts the number of results. If it's less than what was sent as the max ($parameters[ 0 ]), then it returns true, otherwise it returns false.

It can be used with the validator feature of Laravel 4, but has not been tested with Laravel 5 yet.

Comment: It’s worth trimming the $value or it’ll cou8nt an extra word is they end the text with a space. $words = preg_split( '@\s+@i', trim( $value ) );